# does using try catch block in xcode show error on real device?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, debugging, jailbreak

my application is running fine in simulator...but not on real device....and i have jailbroken iphone so i am unable to debug through device...if i use try catch something like this

```
@try
{
Statements
}

@catch (NSException *ex) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ex]
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

will my application show error on alertview before crashing?

if not how could i find where is the bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catching the exception means you are doing something in response to  this "error" coming about and it wont crash the application , thats the point of catching exceptions-to tell how to handle cases where errors arrise so your app wont crash, so yes the alert view will show...

Answer (score 0):

That will work so long as your @catch block doesn't throw any exceptions while trying to build the `UIAlertView`.  Make sure you `release` or `autorelease` it, and support the [UIAlertViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) protocol.

Comment: even if he doesnt implement the protocol the app wont crash until he clicks on the button so the alert will still show

Comment: that's true, just trying to mention any "gotchas"

Comment: using this caus my application to become very slow and it does not show any alertview...am i doing something wrong???

how do i show nsexception as alertview message

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
 initWithTitle:[ex name]
 message:[ex reason]
 delegate:self
 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
 otherButtonTitles: nil];
```

Comment: how do i show alert when application crashed...it's showing error in gdb

Comment: your original post said that you could not use attach GDB, you've confused me